# Two looping JS functions conflicting with each other

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, loops

so I've got these two sets of JavaScript functions that continuously pole my server and, if the database has been updated, the functions do something. Both sets of functions have nothing to do with each other; they're only relationship is that they happen at the same time. Yet for some reason one function is conflicting with the other. Here's what my code looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Stage</title>
<link href="stage.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

 ///////////////////// FUNCTION SET 1 

function loadThumbnail(){
  $.ajax({
    url: 'process_stage_show.php',
    data: 'value=<?php echo $_GET["session"]; ?>',       
    dataType: 'json',                           
    success: function(data){
      var idCurrent = data[0];
      var idVideo = data[1];
      var idSession = data[2];
      var state = data[4];
      if (state ==  1) {
        $('#tv').html('<img src="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/'+ idVideo +'/hqdefault.jpg" width ="800" height="533"/>');
        setTimeout(function(){timedCount2(idCurrent);},1000);
      }
      else {
        setTimeout(function(){timedCount2(idCurrent);},1000);
      }
    }
  });
}

function timedCount2(idCurrent){
  $.ajax({                                      
    url: 'process_stage_show.php',                
    data: 'value=<?php echo $_GET["session"]; ?>',       
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {  
      var idNew = data[0];  
      var idVideo = data[1];
      var idSession = data[2];          
      var state = data[4];          
      if (!(idCurrent == idNew)) {
        window.location.reload();
      }
      else{
        setTimeout(function(){timedCount2(idCurrent);},1000);
      }
    } 
  });
}

 ///////////////////// FUNCTION SET 2 

function loadStage(){
  $.ajax({
    url: 'process_stage_play.php',            
    data: 'value=<?php echo $_GET["session"]; ?>',       
    dataType: 'json',                               
    success: function(data){                    
      var idVideo = data[0];        
      var idCurrent = data[1];
      var idSession = data[2];
      var state = data[4];
      if (state ==  2) {
        //alert("State equal to 2. Do nothing.");
        setTimeout(function(){timedCount(idCurrent);},1000);
      }
      else if (state == 1) {
        //alert("State equal to 1. Open window.");
        popupwindow = window.open ("http://www.youtube.com/watch_popup?v="+ idVideo);
        setTimeout(function(){timedCount(idCurrent);},1000);
      }
      else if (state == 0) {
        //alert("State equal to 0. Close window.");
        popupwindow.close();
        setTimeout(function(){timedCount(idCurrent);},1000);
      }
    }
  });
}

function timedCount(idCurrent){
  $.ajax({                                      
    url: 'process_stage_play.php'             
    data: 'value=<?php echo $_GET["session"]; ?>',
    dataType: 'json',                               
    success: function(data) {  
      var idVideo = data[0];  
      var idNew = data[1];
      var idSession = data[2];          
      var state = data[4];          
      if (idCurrent == idNew) {
        setTimeout(function(){timedCount(idCurrent);},1000);
      }
      else{
        //alert("ID has changed. Re-load stage.");
        loadStage();
      }
    } 
  });
}

</script>
</head>

<body onload="loadStage(); loadThumbnail();">

<div id="tv"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

I'm don't want to go into too much detail about what these sets of functions do (unless requested) as I don't want this post to be REALLY long. But the problem is both these sets of functions work fine by themselves but for some reason if you run them at the same time, the second function set keeps saying popupwindow is not defined when state is equal to 0.

Which makes no sense! Why would the first function set cause that to happen? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well one of the things that the first function sometimes does is reload the window. As soon as that happens, the global variable "popupwindow" will vanish.

It might work to have code in the popped-up window check its "opener" window periodically to see whether it should close itself.

Comment: That window reload cannot occur if the second set of functions opens a new window. Is there some other way they can conflict with each other?

Comment: @AzzyDude what makes you certain that that's really the case?

Comment: I've tested it (i.e. removing the window.reload() and the same glitch still occurs)

Comment: @AzzyDude well what if the second set of functions gets to state 0 before it gets to state 1?

Comment: That cannot happen. When the page loads, the state starts at 2. When you click play, the state switches to 1, and when you click close, the state switches to 0. Then it just constantly bounces back and forth from 1 and 0. 2 is only necessary at the start.

Comment: Well, *something* is happening.  It may be something that you *think* cannot happen, but which nevertheless *is* happening.  Browsers don't just forget about global variables.

Comment: Okay, fair enough, I guess I'll just have to keep debugging it :/

Answer (score 1):

Do I understand correctly that these functions both open a popup window?
If so, some browsers do only open one popup per webpage and if another popup is opened, the old one will be refreshed with the new url.

Thus, one of these functions could lose "its" popup window which would explain your problem.

Comment: Only the second set of functions open a new window. The first set will reload the first page if something else happens. However that reload cannot occur when a new window opens so I don't see how they can conflict with each other?

Comment: @AzzyDude well if the window is not being reloaded, then the variable should not be undefined.

Comment: Exactly! That's why I'm confused. But I can assure you the window.reload function isn't firing.